# Make a .net dll com visible explicitly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, activex

I have an ActiveX dll created in Visual Studio,I have kept the COM Visible to true and when I compile as Admin, the dll gets entered into the registry and is accessible from other applications.

But,how to make this com registered without recompiling.

I tried using regasm,but that creates an entry in registry,but there is no entry in the Win32/WOW64.Also when I try to access it,it is saying that the dll is not strongly registered

Could anyone say,the steps followed by Visual Studio to make an ActiveX dll COM Visible?

Comment: Compiling does not have anything to do with registering.  Running Regasm.exe is a separate task, you for example also need to run it on the user's machine.  If you don't get the registration in the wow64 view then you simply used the wrong version of Regasm.exe.  There are two, a 32-bit and a 64-bit version.  Use the 32-bit version.  You hacked the "not strongly registered" message to death, it is just a warning when you use the /codebase option.  Installing in the GAC is a good idea to avoid DLL Hell.  On the user's machine, not yours.

Comment: Thank you, I used the correct version of regasm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Thank you

“C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\regasm.exe”  “Path\ActiveXLibrary.dll” tlb:ActiveXLibrary.tlb /codebase

actually worked